# Are binary edits of proprietary applications allowed to be shared on SE sites?

Tags: discussion

There are often times when software performs certain unwanted behaviour (like unwanted dialogue boxes for example). Users are often unable to change the program's behavior because the software is not open-sourced, leaving the users really no option to change the software's code and subsequent behaviors.

With low-level hacking of binaries, sometimes users are able to change certain bytes inside the binary with a hex editor that can give them the desired behavior. I imagine this would be something that would come up on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

My question is, do any (or all), of the SE sites prohibit sharing this kind of code-altering information, considering that some binaries are compiled bits of proprietary data, and that there might not be a way to verify the integrity of any such provided alterations of code?

Comment: This type of information is probably illegal in the United States, though it could be argued that these parts of the legislation might be unconstitutional.

Comment: @tripleee Information in itself is can not be illegal, however it might be illegal to share certain types of information in some jurisdictions. If it is, I assume SE would might have a policy that forbids sharing certain types of information. This is exactly what I am asking in my question.

Comment: The [Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) already requires you to abide by applicable laws. It would be untenable for every site to separately have to spell out that using it for stalking, child porn, drug trade, kidnapping, fraud etc etc etc is also forbidden. (The AUP actually expands on a few of these topics, though.)

Comment: Better to ask directly on [reverseengineering.se] as it's very likely that on that site, you might find people who have experience with what is being asked.

Comment: A number of times, I have shared information of that sort on [retrocomputing.se]. So far nobody has complained.